# Multivariable function local minimum using SciPy

Tags: python-3.x, mathematical-optimization

Consider the function:

```
def f(x,y):
    return x + 3*exp(y**2)
```

I was wondering, is it possible to use SciPy.optimize.minimize

to find the minimum value on say [0,1] (the unit interval) (for both, x and y)?

Here is my attempt:

```
bound = (0,1)
bds = [bound,bound]
x_0 = [0,0] (initial guess)
```

And thus,

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(f,x_0,method='SLSQP', \ bounds = bds)
```

But this isn't working.

I keep getting:

"unexpected character after line continuation character" At \ bounds = bnds

Note that I want my x and y to vary over the real numbers on [0,1]

***Edit:***

```
def f(x):
    return x[0] + 3*exp(x[1]**2)

bound = (0,1)
bds = [bound,bound]
x_0 = [0,0] (initial guess)


scipy.optimize.minimize(f,x_0,method='SLSQP', bounds = bds)
```

Is this minimise function looking at only integer values 0 and 1? or is it looking at all real numbers in [0,1] (the unit interval?). If its the first, im not sure how to make it to the second how do I do so?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I have included my attempt

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "isn't working"

Comment: @PranavHosangadi elaborated

Comment: _""unexpected character after line continuation character" At \ bounds = bnds"_: The backslash is a ["line continuation character"](https://www.google.com/search?q=line+continuation+character+python). You can't have anything after that character. Insert a line break after the backslash, or remove the backslash altogether

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Okay, cool. Is my optimise bounds looking at only integer valued x and y or arbitrary real numbers on [0,1] (the unit interval)

Comment: Also, `minimize` wants a function that takes **one** input (read the "Parameters: `fun` part of the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)). That input can be an array of size `n,`. When you want a multivariate minimization, all `n` variables go into that single argument to your function

Comment: @PranavHosangadi alright. I edited it. I included a fix, using what you said. And a question too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code wouldn't work because

> ""unexpected character after line continuation character" At \ bounds = bnds":

is telling you that the "line continuation character" (the backslash) is causing a problem. You can't have anything after that character. Insert a line break after the backslash, or remove the backslash altogether

Once you fix that, you'll get an error saying

```
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

This is because `minimize` wants a function that takes *one* input (read the "Parameters: fun part of the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)). That input can be an array of shape `(n, )`. When you want a multivariate minimization, all n variables go into that single argument to your function

---

Re: *"Is this minimise function looking at only integer values 0 and 1? or is it looking at all real numbers in [0,1] (the unit interval?). If its the first, im not sure how to make it to the second."*

It would be a pretty useless optimizer if it only checked the values at the bounds, don't you think?

This is easy enough to check though! Your current function has a minimum at `[0, 0]`, so it's not a great way to test what the function does. Let's define a function that has a minimum at a different number. For example, let's define a function that has a minimum at `[0.5, 0.5]`

```
def f(X):
    return abs(X[0] - 0.5) * abs(X[1] - 0.5)
```

Running your code gives the result:

```
     fun: 0.0
     jac: array([0., 0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 8
     nit: 2
    njev: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.5, 0.5])
```

which makes it pretty clear that `minimize()` looks in the entire interval.

It doesn't really look at *all* real numbers in the interval though (that would be impossible, given that there are infinite real numbers in any interval). Instead, it uses the optimization algorithms that you specify in the `method` argument.

Answer (score -1):

The optimization result represented as a OptimizeResult object. Important attributes are: x the solution array, success a Boolean flag indicating if the optimizer exited successfully and message which describes the cause of the termination.